# Force user to navigate in sequence in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So, I have a bunch of components and I can navigate between them. However, the business requires the user to navigate to each one of these in turn, i.e., the user should not be able to navigate to the 2nd component if she still hasn't performed all the actions required in the 1st. There are about 5 components, and the user has to interact with all the previous ones in order to get to the last one.

For Angular 1, I used to keep a flag inside a service, which told me if the user had navigated through all the steps in a particular controller. When initializing the next controller in the sequence, I checked if the boolean was true. If not, I programmatically redirected the user to the first controller in the sequence.

I'm wondering if I can do this too in Angular 2 (components replacing controllers, though). Maybe there's a way to do it using a Guard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can use `Guard` to implement this feature, but I don't think it's a better solution. First off, you'd need to have 4 different guards (for 4 subsequent components). Second, the best thing of CanActivateGuard is to completely prevent you from navigating to a view; which is good for protecting restricted content but doesn't offer much in your case.

I'd suggest you to go with your current way, keep a flag inside a common service that is injected in all of these components.